# How do I fill a single row with a dataadapter (or otherwise)

Tags: database, vb.net, sqldataadapter

I have a mysql database on phpmyadmin.
one of the tables in the database has a primary key field and I want to select a record from the database with a specific primary key. obviously this will only return 1 row however I am at a loss as to how I can run the query and then put the result into a single datarow object. all the da.fill overloads require a datset and while this is possible it feels inefficient to define a dataset and always reference it as:

```
dataset.tables("table").rows(0).item.....
```

when I could be using:

```
row.item.....
```

TL;DR, how can I populate a datarow with a dataadapter in vb.net?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest retrieving your data into the DataGridView control. To do this you can use the code I have inputted below from one of my projects.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient


Public Class Form1

Dim dbConnection As SqlConnection
Dim dbCommand As SqlCommand
Dim dbAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
Dim DataSet As New DataSet
Dim strSQL As String
Dim dbCount As String

Public Sub SQLConnect()
    dbConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=connectionhere\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=line_log;Integrated Security=True")
    dbConnection.Open()
End Sub

Public Sub SQLCommand()
    dbCommand = New SqlCommand(strSQL, dbConnection)
End Sub

Public Sub SQLAdapter()
    dbAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, dbConnection)
End Sub

Public Sub SQLDisconnect()
    dbConnection.Close()
End Sub

Public Sub DGVLoad()
    Try
        SQLConnect()
        strSQL = "SELECT [item] FROM [table] WHERE ([item] = 'value')"
        SQLAdapter()
        DataSet.Clear()
        dbAdapter.Fill(DataSet)
        SQLDisconnect()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DataSet.Tables(0)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DGVLoad()
End Sub
```

Comment: While this code may work, it is supporting a bad programming pattern and promotes tightly coupled unmaintainable code, so no upvote from me.